# Why can't python glob detect my thumbdrive (and what can I do about it?)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, glob

So I got a thumb-drive plugged in. Its at `/dev/sdb1`. Its got some files on it, and it is mounted. I do

```
>>> glob.glob("/dev/sdb1/*")
[]
```

Why is this and what can I do about it?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2

Comment: Files are accessed through their mount point, e.g. `/mnt/mydrive/*` and not through their `/dev` node.

Answer (score 0):

You are globbing on the *device file*.
If you want to access the files, you need to glob on the *mount point*, which is (depending on your system) probably something like "/run/media/$USER/something", "/media/something" or "/mnt/something", where "something" might be sdb1 or the thumb-drive's partition label.

Answer (score 0):

> "... and it is mounted."

But it is not mounted on `/dev/sdb1`; that is simply its device file. Examine the actual mount point to find the files stored on the drive.