# How to see where a device file was mounted to?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, filesystems, usb

Given something like `/dev/sdb1`, how can I find out where it was automounted to in linux in python (since using it directly like a directory does not work)?

(Continued from [Why can't python glob detect my thumbdrive (and what can I do about it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658332/why-cant-python-glob-detect-my-thumbdrive-and-what-can-i-do-about-it))

Comment: You can find this information in `/proc/mounts`. The first space separated field is the device and the second is the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subprocess with `lsblk` and parse that  or just parse `/etc/mtab`:

```
def find_mount(dev):
    with open("/etc/mtab") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(dev):
                return line.split(None, 2)[1]


print(find_mount("/dev/sdb1"))
```